# hibernate query or criteria to use when considering thoroughly on performance

Tags: hibernate

I'm using hibernate integrated with Spring.

If I'm very concerned about performance should I use Hibernate query or criteria?

Also, should I use hibernate query or criteria for performance for `query.list()` since it is very slow on big data lists?

Comment: "Performance" is a broad term. Please, consider better defining your use case and posting questions about actual problems you are facing.